# Why embedding_lookup_sparse and string_to_hash_bucket in tensorflow slow with large number of rows of embeddings

Tags: tensorflow

In tensorflow embedding_lookup_sparse lookup the row of embeddings according the sp_ids. I think it's similar to random access. However when the shape of embeddings is large, i.e 10M rows, the inference spent more time than when the embeddings only has about 1M rows. As I think, the lookup phase and is similar to random access and the hash function spent constant time which is all fast and less sensitive with the size. Is there any wrong with my thought? Is there any way to optimize so that the inference can be faster? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it is caused by the embedding_lookup? In my case I also have millions of rows to lookup. It is very fast if I use GradientDecend optimizer. It is very slow if I use Adam or the others. Probably it is not the embedding_lookup opr slows down your training but other oprs that depend on the total number of params.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that "embedding_lookup" works slowly when there are many rows in table.

And you may figure out why by reading its source code. Here is the source code in "embedding_lookup":

[image of the source code: variable "np" is the length of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awptI.png)

[image of the source code: loop with np](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeIev.png)

As you see there is a loop with a time complexity of O(table length) appearing here. In fact "embedding_lookup" use dynamic partition to separate input data into several partition of ids, and then use this loop to embed words vectors to each id's partition. In my opinion, this trick can fix the time complexity to O(table length) no matter how big the input data is.

So I think the best way for you to increase training speed is to input more samples in each batch.

Comment: I think this statement is not correct. np = len(params) is just the # of partitions for the embedding variable, has nothing to do with the actual # of rows of the embedding